# Hide a div upon option change in select dropdown in HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To get straight to the point here's I want to accomplish. I want to hide a certain DIV when a certain `<OPTION>` in `<SELECT>` was selected.

Here's my HTML markup:

**THE SELECT**

```
<select name="cutoffselect" id="cutoff" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="padding-right: 80px;">
        <option value="">Choose One</option>
        <option value="daily">Daily</option>
        <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
        <option value="semimonthly">Semi Monthly</option>
        <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
  </select>
```

and the DIV I want to hide if DAILY was selected.

**THE PERIOD**

```
<div class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;" title='Filter By' id = "perioddiv">   
    <!--PERIOD-->
       <label for="period" style="padding-right: 10px;margin-top:7px;" visible="false">Period</label>
          <select name="period" id="period" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <option value="">Choose Period</option>
                <option value="">1</option>
                <option value="">2</option>
                <option value="">3</option>
                <option value="">4</option>
                <option value="">5</option>
          </select>
    <!--PERIOD-->
  </div>
```

I have tried using different query but I cannot do what I want. Here's the query I used but its not functioning and if I may ask for another jQuery suggestion that actually might work the greater. Thanks to all in advance.

**HERE'S THE QUERY**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#cutoffselect").change(function(){
       $("#perioddiv div:eq(" + $(this).attr("selectedIndex") + ")").show();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: which you want hide either div or something?

Comment: I want to hide the div with id = "perioddiv" when I select the "daily" in select dropdown. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: you have select `id=cutoff` and used `$("#cutoffselect")`, please correct it. And I did not understand the `$("#perioddiv div:eq(" + $(this).attr("selectedIndex") + ")").show();`, what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         $("#cutoff").change(function(){
             if($(this).val()=='daily'){
                 $('#perioddiv').hide();
             }
             else{
                 $('#perioddiv').show();
             }
         });
     });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer.

$('#cutoff').change(function () {

```
    if ($('#cutoff').find(":selected").text() == 'Daily') {
        $('#perioddiv').hide();
    } else {
        $('#perioddiv').show();
    }

});
```

jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/LNMW3/
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide div with `id=perioddiv` when `daily` option selected, you can try below jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     // bind change event using '#cutoff' as select id="cutoff"
     $("#cutoff").change(function(){
       // hide if selected value is "daily"
       if($(this).val() == "daily")
          $("#perioddiv").hide();
       else
          $("#perioddiv").show();
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eKJ2/)

Using the ID's you can easily sort this out by using:

```
$("#selectorID").hide();
```

Comment: Oh Sorry. Thanks Ma'am for the help. Sincerest apology for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $("#cutoff").change(function () {
    if (this.value == "daily") {
        $("#perioddiv").hide();
    } else {
        $("#perioddiv").show();
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B4N33/)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the selected option is daily and then hide the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#cutoff').change(function(){

        if($('#cutoff option:selected').val() == 'daily')
        {
            $('#perioddiv').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#perioddiv').show();
        }

     });

});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nathvarun/n7f2a/)

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$('#period').change(function(){

    // check if "daily" is selected
    if($(this).val() == "daily") {
        $('#perioddiv').hide();
    }

});
```